# d3.js dropdown menu - select related nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the code below for creating a dropdown:

```D3
var arrayOfGroups = [];

function makearray(){
  node.each(function(d){
    if(arrayOfGroups.indexOf(d.group) < 0){
      arrayOfGroups.push(d.group)
    }
  })
  console.log(arrayOfGroups)
  return arrayOfGroups;
}

var newArray = makearray();

var container = document.getElementById('selectContainer')
var dropdown = creatSelectDropDown('thisDropdown', newArray);

dropdown.onchange = function(event) {
  console.log(event)
  node.style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('stroke-width', '1px');

  node.filter(function(d) {
      return d.group == event.id;
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      console.log('d')
    })
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('stroke-width', '5px')
}

container.appendChild(dropdown)

function creatSelectDropDown(id, array) {

  var dropdown = document.createElement("select");
  dropdown.id = id;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = array[i];
    option.id = array[i];
    dropdown.options.add(option);
  }
  return dropdown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This code selects nodes, the problem is that I want this code to choose the nodes related to their ID and that's what I couldn't make it work and it has only one option that is undefined. I want it to show me some other options like map1, map2, etc. and I have the data below:

```js
var thisData = {
 "nodes" : [{
   "id" : "C47676",
   "name" : "name1",
   "x" : 1209,
   "y" : 41
  }, {
   "id" : "C58435",
   "name" : "name2",
   "x" : 483,
   "y" : 227
  }, {
          .
          .
          .
        }],
 "links" : [{
   "id" : "K14724 ",
   "name" : "name3",
   "x1" : 983,
   "y1" : 461,
   "x2" : 983,
   "y2" : 524,
   "x3" : 985,
   "y3" : 524,
   "x4" : 985,
   "y4" : 461
  }, {
   "id" : "K85944 ",
   "name" : "name4",
   "x1" : 983,
   "y1" : 524,
   "x2" : 983,
   "y2" : 525,
   "x3" : 985,
   "y3" : 525,
   "x4" : 985,
   "y4" : 524
  }, {
          .
          .
          .
        }]};
```

Question is: I need help to choose the nodes according to their ID that doesn't work and I need some options like map1, map2 instead undefined.
Is there any idea that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ID instead of this :

```
function makearray(){
  node.each(function(d){
    if(arrayOfGroups.indexOf(d.group) < 0){
      arrayOfGroups.push(d.group)
    }
  })
  console.log(arrayOfGroups)
  return arrayOfGroups;
}
```

You would use ID instead of group like so :

```
function makearray(){
  node.each(function(d){
    if(arrayOfGroups.indexOf(d.id) < 0){
      arrayOfGroups.push(d.id)
    }
  })
  console.log(arrayOfGroups)
  return arrayOfGroups;
}
```

I would recommend renaming the array to `arrayOfIds` as it isnt groups anymore.

And then in the onchange I would compare d.id rather than d.group. But there is a mistake on the line where you compare :

```
return d.group == event.id;
```

It this should be  :

```
return d.group == event.target.value;
```

The target.value is the value of the option tag. As that is what you want to do, get the nodes with the same ID as the value you have picked. No idea why you changed this. The only thing you should have changed is what node attribute you want to compare to.

So seen as you want to compare ID's it should be :

```
return d.id == event.target.value;
```

As for the map1, map2, I have no idea what youre talking about here ...

Comment: it highlights every single node not the one related

Comment: how can it ?? ID is suppose to be unique. Set up a fiddle and ill show you

Comment: that is exactly what I didn't get, I changed ID to name as well, doesn't matter which one I choose it highlights all the nodes

Comment: did you change it in both, when you make the array and when you filter ?

Comment: I somehow managed to choose the one related to that ID but now what it does is choosing that one and makes the rest all black and 1px

Comment: do you not read the code you have ? Before you filter the nodes you set the stroke to white and width of the stroke to 1px. Come on mate

Comment: I was just writing problem solved, I uncommented that part but forgot to close it somewhere

Comment: Ive said this before, I recommend you understand what your code is doing. It seems like youre being a bit lazy when it comes to solving your problems. Atleast its solved now :) I would also recommend, in future questions, create a fiddle. Luckily I knew what you were on a bout but someone else wouldnt have a clue

Comment: is this applicable to choose the lines by name or ID? I think I can apply it with small changes

Comment: of course. Just create an array from the line ID's instead of the node ID's and on change filter the lines if the ID is the same as the dropdown value. 2 changes needed

Comment: it breaks the nodes one too, that's why I asked

Comment: what do you mean breaks the nodes ones two ? Just create a new function to create a new drop down for the links, create a new makenewarray for the links id's and it shouldnt conflict with the nodes at all

Comment: what is that you just sent ? There's no data ? I'm going to leave this now. You're not really understanding/listening to what i have said

Comment: yes i did and as it says link isn't defined in the console log i know youre missing code. Do you read the console log ? Your getting on the verge of wasting my time

Comment: I can even see on my phone idk why you can't you open. Sorry for trouble. Anyways I got a working code the thing is that they don't work at the same time I need to choose links or nodes it doesn't add two dropdowns

Comment: go on your pc and put on together then and ill take a look at that